# Ubuntu Gnome RAID GUI Tool

Tags: linux, raid, ubuntu, software-raid

I have installed Ubuntu server ("Jaunty") onto a hardware RAID 1 setup.  I have now (after successful install) added 2 new drives which I'd like to also have in hardware (or software) RAID 1.

When I setup a hardware RAID array for the new drives, the next boot into Ubuntu failed miserably.  During startup it hangs just after a line which says something about RAID array missing or not enough parameters.

I tried this even on another controller int he same machine, had the same problem.

Having given up on that, I tried using MDADM to create a software RAID volume, but I must have done something wrong becasue when I go:  `sudo cat /proc/mdstat` I get a /dev/md_d0 device listed, but whe I try to remove or touch that device in anyway, I get the message 'file or device not found'.

Ignoring THAT issue, I then tried to create a new array as /dev/md0 using MDADM, but it lists one of the drives (specifically /dev/sda1) as being busy or in use - despite having blown away all partitions on the drive and creating a fresh single partition on the while drive.

In either case, something really weird seems to be going on, and my real-life linux people are no help becasue they dont have any xperience in theis area (I am a linux noob).  In order to help me, to help myself, I was wondering if there was a tool for gnome I could use on the (gnome-core/x-windows I installed) to help me manage these arrays.  I installed Gparted, but it doesnt seem to help me with RAIDed volumes.

What GUI RAID tools for gnome can I use to help configure this 2nd array, like a GUI version of LVM or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit web based, but you could try the tool: **[webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)**

Comment: Yes it di, thank you very much for your help.  I still had to screw-arround with the console, but the webmin pointed me in the right direction for sure! :)